# Unbuffered output with cout

Tags: c++, cout

How can you get unbuffered output from cout, so that it instantly writes to the console without the need to flush (similar to cerr)?

I thought it could be done through rdbuf()->pubsetbuf, but this doesn't seem to work.  The following code snippet below is supposed to immediately output to the console, and then wait a few seconds.  But instead, it just waits, and only outputs when the program exits and the buffer is flushed.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::cout.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0, 0);
        std::cout << "A";
        sleep(5);
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can set the [`std::ios_base::unitbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags) [flag](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/fmtflags/) to flush output after each output operation either by calling [`std::ios_base::setf`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/setf/):

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios::unitbuf);
```

or using the [`std::unitbuf`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/unitbuf/) [manipulator](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/library/manipulators/):

```
std::cout << std::unitbuf;
```

Comment: This solution indeed worked for me, thanks! A note to others: the buffering appears to happen when using cout or printf and happens even if a newline is used at the end of the line.