# execute function on pushbutton event

Tags: c++, qt

complete beginner here.
I'm trying to execute a function whenever pushButton is pressed, but it only gets executed after I close the main window. How can I make this happen instantly whenever the button is pressed?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    cout << "test";
}
```

"test" is printed only after the window is closed.
Same thing happens when I call my own function.

Comment: Try turning off buffering for your `cout` statement.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377084/unbuffered-output-with-cout.

Answer (score 0):

if you are **just** debugging/testing and you don't intend for your final application to use this, you could try the following:

```
#include <QDebug>

    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        qDebug() << "test";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}
```

By providing the endl; the set:cout buffer is flushed, you could also add 
`std::cout << std::flush;` to flush the buffer.

Also please [avoid using namespace std;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: You see in code that you added the namespace: `using namespace std;`, so it is not necessary to use `std ::`

Comment: @eyllanesc True, however, in general it is better practice to remove using namespace std and prefix with `std::`.  so to be consistent I should use `std::endl` as well, i edited my answer to make it consistent. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: That I know, it is a bad practice but that does not influence the OP.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for pointing out the inconsistency in my answer. I decided to edit it to make it conform best practice, rather than taking out the std::