# std::cout output not printed till program ends

Tags: c++, cout, getchar

I have a few `std::cout` statements and few of them do not print output to console till program ends. But it i put `getchar()`, it starts printing output. Why does it happen, can someone please explain?

Comment: Also see [Unbuffered output with cout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377084/unbuffered-output-with-cout?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue may be because you are not trying to flush your output. You can try like this:

```
std::cout << "some text" << std::flush;
```

or like

```
std::cout << "some text" << std::endl;
```

The standard output is buffered and on newline the buffer is flushed.

Comment: And standard output is also flushed when **standard input** is read, which is why `getchar()` works.