# Unexpectedly blocky output to console from threaded functions

Tags: c++, multithreading

In the following program, I was expecting an (approximately) alternating pattern of red and green dots generated by the two threads to print *as*, or while the program was running. However, I fail to understand why the sequence of dots are printed in blocks only after 10s of seconds are up on my M1 Mac mini. I can't see why the console can't keep up with dots printing at `1Hz`.

###### `main.cpp`

```
#include <thread>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/color.h>

void work(const fmt::color &c) {
    int seconds = 600;
    for (int i = 0; i < seconds; ++i) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        fmt::print(fmt::fg(c), ".");
    }
}

int main() {
    auto thread0 = std::thread([&]() {
        work(fmt::color::red);
    });
    auto thread1 = std::thread([&]() {
        work(fmt::color::green);
    });
    thread0.join();
    thread1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output after just beyond `3` seconds:

```
......
```

Actual output after `3` seconds

Why don't the dots print in *real-time* as it were?

Comment: [a 1 second sleep_for could be more than 1 second](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Comment: What happens if you print `".\n"` instead of just `"."`?

Comment: @JaMiT Interesting! The issue with blocky output disappears.

Comment: See also [std::cout output not printed till program ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388042/)

Comment: @JaMiT Thanks. Using `auto s = fmt::format(fmt::fg(c), ".");
        std::cout << s << std::flush;` seems to work.