# Is it possible to make std::cout flush automatically before program termination in various failure cases (e.g., exception)

Tags: c++, cout

If an exception is thrown, the lack of a flushed stdout makes it harder to diagnose the issue. Are there any mitigations that can be used? (e.g., termination hooks, compiler flags, etc). I can understand that in a segfault it's probably very difficult to flush, but I would think that it for uncaught exceptions in arbitrary threads, it should be at least theoretically possible.

Note: The situation is complicated slightly by the fact that multiple threads may be used. So catching exceptions in `main` will not work for other threads.

Comment: Why tag this question `c`?

Comment: Just disable buffering.

Comment: Why leave your exceptions uncaught?  Can't you put a try-catch block around them when launched, and flush in there?  For segfaults - you can use sigaction (on Linux/UNIX) to catch segfaults and try flushing things - no guarantees - could even deadlock depending on what was happening when the fault happened.   Also consider when stuff is important enough to flush after writing (though doing that too often is slow).  If you're really serious, you could write messages into shared memory regions that won't be lost if your app crashes.

Comment: @Barmar Why not flush the buffer instead? Disabling buffering has performance implications that may not necessarily be acceptable.

Comment: @eerorika Because you can't necessarily do that if the program terminates abnormally.

Comment: @Barmar You can if program terminates due to uncaught exception, as in the question.

Comment: @eerorika It says "various failure cases". Exception is just an example.

Comment: OTOH, it does seem to admit that the solution won't work for segfault.

Comment: Write debugging output to `std::cerr`. That's what it's for. It's unit buffered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When program terminates due to uncaught exception, `std::terminate` will be called. This calls the terminate handler that has been registered using `std::set_terminate`. Within this terminate handler, you can flush the standard output streams.

`std::terminate` is also called in some other cases such as throwing exception out of `noexcept` function, destruction of joinable `std::thread`, direct call from user code etc.

This does not help if the program is terminated by the operating system. That can only be solved by [disabling buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377084/unbuffered-output-with-cout). You could **try** to flush in a signal handler as a desperate measure, but that is not guaranteed to succeed, nor to have desired behaviour, because flushing is not async safe operation.

Comment: @Barmar better than nothing.

Comment: @Barmar I expanded a bit to mention that all failure cases are not covered by `std::terminate`