# Does std::cout guarantee to print a string if it doesn't end with a newline?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, newline, iostream, flush

I've heard that the following program isn't guaranteed to print the string on every platform and to actually do it you need to add `\n` to the end or flush the buffer by other means. Is that true or does the standard guarantee the expected output anyway?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!";
}
```

Comment: Why worry? If you need to have this output guaranteed, just `std::flush` it and forget it.

Comment: `cout` is typically* line-buffered (* implementation-defined!), if so then it would usually need a line break or explicit flush, yes (unless the buffer fills up, then it is flushed). Though, the buffer should get flushed automatically on program exit

Comment: Why minuses? Explain pls what I need to change.

Comment: @RemyLebeau *should* or must? I.e. is it specified by the standard?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik worry at least for educational purposes.

Comment: @cppbest it is not *guaranteed*, no. In fact, one way it won't flush automatically at exit is if the process ends due to `std::terminate()` being called, unless you disable buffering or use `std::set_terminate()` to flush manually. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62326830/

Comment: @cppbest -- "should". Back in the olden days there were mainframe systems with record-oriented I/O systems, and it took great creativity to implement streaming I/O. Without a newline output would sometimes unavoidably fail, so the C (and by inheritance C++) standard allows the system to not output text that isn't followed by a newline. In practice this is not a significant issue today unless the program exits abnormally.

Comment: "Why minuses?" - I think because you tagged language-lawyer and haven't made an attempt to look it up in the specification nor cite the specification.

Comment: It is guaranteed to print it, there's no guarantee however of when the string will appear on your terminal

Comment: @AlanBirtles can u prodive a link to the relevant paragraph in the standard?

Comment: @ThomasWeller well, I tagged it so in order to find the relevant specification quote.

Comment: Somehow, a question about the standard has not received a single response with a reference to the standard.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer: which is easily possible because the question is just 22 minutes old and finding a quote in the standard may easily take 2 hours.

Comment: `'\n'` doesn't flush a buffer, `std::endl` does.

Comment: @Evg in general, yes. But when `cout` is line-buffered (as it *usually* is in many implementations), then writing a `'\n'` does flush the buffer. But this is implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Didn't know that, thanks. I should take a look at some implementation that does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[ios.init]/1** The class `Init` describes an object whose construction ensures the construction of the eight objects declared in `<iostream>` (29.4) that associate file stream buffers with the standard C streams provided for by the functions declared in `<cstdio>` (29.12.1).
>
> **[ios.init]/3**
> `Init();`
> *Effects:* Constructs and initializes the objects `cin`, `cout`, `cerr`, `clog`, `wcin`, `wcout`, `wcerr`, and `wclog` if they have not already been constructed and initialized.
>
> **[ios.init]/4**
> `~Init();`
> *Effects:* If there are no other instances of the class still in existence, calls `cout.flush()`, `cerr.flush()`, `clog.flush()`, `wcout.flush()`, `wcerr.flush()`, `wclog.flush()`.

So therefore, `std::cout.flush()` would be called as part of the program's normal termination sequence, by the destructor of the same object (sometimes known as [nifty counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter)) that ensured `std::cout` was initialized in the first place.

Comment: "If there are no other instances of the class still in existence" — is it possible there **are** those instances?

Comment: @cppbest: If you create them, then yes. More likely, if a library creates them.

Comment: @MSalters does it mean that it's possible that `cout.flush()` will not be called and `\n` is required?

Comment: @cppbest: In theory (if you allocate it on the heap). In practice, nobody does that, and global objects are all destroyed at program exit.

Comment: There's a static variable of type `ios_base::Init` defined in every translation unit that includes <iostream>. They are initialized in some unspecified order at the program startup, and destroyed at the program termination. They use a counter to figure out which one of them is the first to be initialized or the last to be destroyed. The first one to be initialized initializes `std::cout` et al; the last one to be destroyed calls `flush` on them.

Comment: This technique - again, sometimes referred to as "nifty counters" - guarantees that `std::cout` et al are available in constructors and destructors of global objects, and doesn't fall victim to the so-called [static initialization order fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)